# Give color to a buffered image in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, pixel

I have a buffered image that looks something like this. [image]

How do I give it color? I am new to image processing in java any help would be greatly appreciated. This is a sample of the code that generates this picture.

```
   public BufferedImage getDifferenceImage(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
    int width1 = img1.getWidth(); // Change - getWidth() and getHeight() for BufferedImage
    int width2 = img2.getWidth(); // take no arguments
    int height1 = img1.getHeight();
    int height2 = img2.getHeight();
    if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) {
        System.err.println("Error: Images dimensions mismatch");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // NEW - Create output Buffered image of type RGB
    BufferedImage outImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Modified
    long diff;
    int result; // Stores output pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < height1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width1; j++) {
            int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(j, i);
            int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(j, i);
            int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g1 = (rgb1 >> 8) & 0xff;
            int b1 = (rgb1) & 0xff;
            int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g2 = (rgb2 >> 8) & 0xff;
            int b2 = (rgb2) & 0xff;
            diff = Math.abs(r1 - r2); // Change
            diff += Math.abs(g1 - g2);
            diff += Math.abs(b1 - b2);
            diff /= 255; // Change - Ensure result is between 0 - 255
            // Make the difference image gray scale
            // The RGB components are all the same
            result = (diff << 16) | (diff << 8) | diff;
            outImg.setRGB(j, i, result); // Set result
        }
    }

    // Now return
    return outImg;
}
```

Comment: What does the original look like?  How do you create/load it?

Comment: Are you loading the image from a file or generating it programmatically (or a mixture of both)? Does this image has a transparent background, or is it literally as is as shown in the image you posted? Do you need to process the image itself or would it suffice to set a background color and then draw the image on top of it?

Comment: I am trying to find the difference between two images. This is the resulting image that seeks to highlight this difference.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the "difference" between the images? Also, how exactly do you want to add color to this image? Do you want to highlight part of it with color (which would involve painting over part of the image with a color with an alpha value)?

Comment: Yes. I just want it visible. It is too dark.

Comment: @user3078335 try the color model?

Comment: Can you briefly describe what your code does in the question itself? Remember, it is generally not sufficient to post giant blocks of code on Stackoverflow without also posting some sort of human explanation. The goal should be to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user3078335 - You should at least include the code that creates that black and white image.  This is because when you look at my answer in comparison to your question, it is incongruent.  People won't know where the code that I provided came from, when it was a simple modification to the code you posted in the past.  I recommend that you place some code so that people will know what you had, and what I did to fix it.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay. I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code where you are calculating the difference between colours where instead of setting each of the colour channels to be the same and it generating grayscale, try setting each colour channel to be their own respective differences rather than adding up the differences in each colour channel.  In other words, try this:

```
// Modified - Changed to int as pixels are ints
int rDiff, gDiff, bDiff;
int result; // Stores output pixel
for (int i = 0; i < height1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width1; j++) {
        int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(j, i);
        int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(j, i);
        int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g1 = (rgb1 >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b1 = (rgb1) & 0xff;
        int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g2 = (rgb2 >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b2 = (rgb2) & 0xff;
        rDiff = Math.abs(r1 - r2); // Change
        gDiff = Math.abs(g1 - g2);
        bDiff = Math.abs(b1 - b2);
        result = (rDiff << 16) | (gDiff << 8) | bDiff;
        outImg.setRGB(j, i, result); // Set result
    }
}
```

---

## Edit - August 1, 2014

You mentioned that if there is **any** difference between two pixels in their corresponding spots, we should set this colour to yellow (or purple / magenta).  We can very easily do that.  Simply calculate the added difference between all of the channels, and if it's not equal to 0, set the output colour to yellow (or purple / magenta).  Else, just keep the colour the way it is.  I'm also going to assume that you'll want to keep the pixels from  **image 1** the same if there is no difference.  If you want to keep the pixels from **image 2** to be the same, just change the variable in the code.  In other words:

```
// Modified - Changed to int as pixels are ints
int diff;
int result; // Stores output pixel
for (int i = 0; i < height1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width1; j++) {
        int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(j, i);
        int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(j, i);
        int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g1 = (rgb1 >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b1 = (rgb1) & 0xff;
        int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g2 = (rgb2 >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b2 = (rgb2) & 0xff;
        diff = Math.abs(r1 - r2); // Change
        diff += Math.abs(g1 - g2);
        diff += Math.abs(b1 - b2);

        // Check for any differences
        if (diff != 0) {
           r1 = 255;  // If there is, set output to yellow
           g1 = 255;
           b1 = 0;
           /* // Use this for purple / magenta
           r1 = 255;
           g1 = 0;
           b1 = 255; */
        }

        // If there are no differences, r1, g1 and b1
        // will contain the original colours for image 1
        // If there is, then r1, g1, b1 will be set to yellow

        // Set output pixel
        result = (r1 << 16) | (g1 << 8) | b1;
        outImg.setRGB(j, i, result); // Set result
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question. I am trying to modify outImg a bit. As you can see, the image produced is dark. Is it possible for outImg to keep the colors of the original images while highlighting the differences as a yellow or a pink color. A hint on how to do it would be awesome!!

Comment: @user3078335 You can do this two ways.  Do you want **any difference** to be highlighted as a full yellow, or do you want the intensity of the yellow to change depending on the difference of the two colours? (i.e. the more difference there is, the stronger the yellow appears)

Comment: the first i think would be fine. I just want to keep the colors of the original image and highlight the differences as yellow.

Comment: @user3078335 - Very easy fix.  Did you want to make this a new question, or should I reply here?

Comment: you can reply here if you want. I can make a new question as well. Whatever you want kind sir.

Comment: @user3078335 - I'll just modify here.  Don't want to be a reputation hog :).  Wait for 5 minutes

Comment: @user3078335 - Done.  Good luck!

Comment: hello Ray! It seems like the intensity changes would have worked better instead. Full yellow color was not too great. I asked a question. This is the link to the new question. See if you can help out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088808/maintain-images-original-color-content

Comment: sorry for how unclear that question was. I was just asking how I could keep the text in the image as it was in the original image. When I implement the modifications you made, the texts disappear. And it seems like the intensity changes would have been a better idea, as the yellow seems to be everywhere. That's what I wanted to ask, and I wanted to create a new question that you could answer to enable you enhance your reputation for all the help you have provided.

Comment: @user3078335 - No problem.  Let me take a look at it.  I voted by accident as this was in the close votes queue and I was reviewing posts.  I didn't realize that your post was actually this question.  I'll have a look soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **[this](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/changing-the-colormodel-of-a-bufferedimage)**

```
BufferedImage yourFile =
```

You can create a color model(see the link for example)

```
private static ColorModel createColorModel(int n) {

        // Create a simple color model with all values mapping to
        // a single shade of gray
        // nb. this could be improved by reusing the byte arrays

        byte[] r = new byte[16];
        byte[] g = new byte[16];
        byte[] b = new byte[16];

        for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            r[i] = (byte) n;
            g[i] = (byte) n;
            b[i] = (byte) n;
        }
        return new IndexColorModel(4, 16, r, g, b);
    }
```